# Linq group by year, month and employeeid then sum total working hours

Tags: linq

I'm using this code to group the rows by year, month and employeeId.

```
var dtrSummary = from dtr in db.DTRs
                 group dtr by new { dtr.Date.Year, dtr.Date.Month, dtr.EmployeeId } into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Year = g.Key.Year,
                     Month = g.Key.Month,
                     NoOfDays = g.Count(),
                     FullName = db.EmployeeRates.Where(e => e.Id == g.Key.EmployeeId).Select(e => e.FullName).FirstOrDefault(),

                     Time1 = // Get total hours between two datetime
                             // DateTime timein = new DateTime(year, month, day, tihh1, timm1, 0);
                             // DateTime timeout = new DateTime(year, month, day, tohh1, tomm1, 0);
                             // Timespan totalTime1 = timeout - timein;
                 };
```

But i don't know how to get total hours using linq group by like you see above.

This is my table:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Date   | Timeinhh | Timeinmm | Timeouthh | Timeoutmm | EmployeeId |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10/1/2015 | 9        | 0        | 18        | 0         | 1          |
| 10/2/2015 | 9        | 0        | 18        | 0         | 2          |
| 10/3/2015 | 9        | 0        | 18        | 0         | 1          |
| 10/4/2015 | 9        | 0        | 18        | 0         | 2          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to calculate each hours before grouping DTRs.

```
var DTRs2 = db.DTRs.ToList().Select(d => new
{
    Date = d.Date,
    Hours = new DateTime(d.Date.Year, d.Date.Month, d.Date.Day, d.Timeouthh, d.Timeoutmm, 0)
                .Subtract(new DateTime(d.Date.Year, d.Date.Month, d.Date.Day, d.Timeinhh, d.Timeinmm, 0)).TotalHours,
    EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId
}).ToList();

var dtrSummary =
    (from dtr in DTRs2
     group dtr by new { dtr.Date.Year, dtr.Date.Month, dtr.EmployeeId } into g
     select new
     {
         Year = g.Key.Year,
         Month = g.Key.Month,
         NoOfDays = g.Count(),
         EmpId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
         FullName = db.EmployeeRates.Where(e => e.Id == g.Key.EmployeeId).Select(e => e.FullName).FirstOrDefault(),

         Time1 = g.Sum(dtr => dtr.Hours) // Get total hours between two datetime
     });
```

I also recommend to define another class/table like this rather than using anonymous type every time:

```
public class DTRDetails
{
    public DTR DTR { get; set; }
    public EmployeeRate EmployeeRate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return EmployeeRate.FullName; }
    }

    public int Hours
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(new DateTime(DTR.Date.Year, DTR.Date.Month, DTR.Date.Day, DTR.Timeinhh, DTR.Timeinmm, 0)
                             .Subtract(new DateTime(DTR.Date.Year, DTR.Date.Month, DTR.Date.Day, DTR.Timeouthh, DTR.Timeoutmm, 0))).TotalHours;
        }
    }

    public int Hours2
    {
        get
        {
            // return something
        }
    }

    public int Hours3
    {
        get { return Hours - Hours2; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jhmt Thank you for your answer i think this is the answer to my question, but i'm getting this error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Hi @JohnLouieDelaCruz I've updated my answer. If you generate the new list with using `ToList`  method like that, this will work.

Comment: You are welcome @JohnLouieDelaCruz By the way, you can also try `System.Data.Objects.EntityFucntions.DiffHours`:)

Comment: Hi @jhmt i have another question, how to get sum of multiple timespans for example i will add new property for example TotalHours = Hours + Hours2

Comment: Hi @JohnLouieDelaCruz I've updated my answer. In order to do that, I recommend to use a new class or table like in my updated answer.